# How do I create custom arrows in slick slider that change image on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I'm using slick slider https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. I want my custom arrows to change when i hover over them.

Below is the javascript i've used to customise the left and right arrows in the slider. But i want the prevArrow image to be replaced with another image when i hover over the prevArrow. And similarly the nextArrow image to be replaced with a another image when the right arrow is hovered.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.slider').slick({
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/449-4492390_arrow-to-the-left-png-icon-free-arrow.png'>",
nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/free-right-arrow-symbol-png-vector-arrow-right-vector-115632158025eetnpo2gn.png'>"
    });
});

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

I tried something like this in CSS (see below), but it's not working. Maybe because the new image is appearing behind the previous image...?
How could i make a new image appear in place of the old arrow image?

```
  .slick-prev:hover {
     background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/413195/pexels-photo-413195.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat !important;
    }
```

Edit after comment from @Manjuboyz: below is a working example of my code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.slider').slick({
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/584799/pexels-photo-584799.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'>",
nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/536/road-street-sign-way.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260'>"
    });
});
```

```css
.slick-prev:hover {
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/413195/pexels-photo-413195.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat !important;
  }
  
.slick-next:hover {
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/413195/pexels-photo-413195.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" data-slick='{"arrows": true'}>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3052361/pexels-photo-3052361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/830891/pexels-photo-830891.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/373912/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462331/pexels-photo-462331.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162031/dubai-tower-arab-khalifa-162031.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/290595/pexels-photo-290595.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1823739/pexels-photo-1823739.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1769371/pexels-photo-1769371.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the html code as well or can you create a snippet to show us?

Comment: i'll try and produce something. The problem is i'm working on shopify, so all my html is a combination of html and liquid coding. I'll try and remove as much liquid coding as i can. hopefully it will be enough for it to make sense.

Comment: I made a snippet behalf of you, can you reproduce the issue like what you need?

Comment: I did it, but then i couldn't save it because there were too many characters.  So i've tried to include the javascript as a web link, but that's giving me an error now. i'm trying to figure out why unless you know a simple way to fix it.

Comment: i've fixed it :) is that what you were wanting @Manjuboyz ?

Comment: great! so now tell me what you have to fix from the snippet above, if you can explain in detail

Comment: Currently my arrows for the slider are images. I defined them in the prevArrow and nextArrow setting. What i want is for the images to change to new images (which i define in the code) when i hover over them. I tried adding some CSS for the class .slick-prev:hover as i've shown in my question. I hoped that i could define a replacement image in there somehow that would appear when the original image was hovered over. But it doesn't seem to be working. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, the arrow images haven't come out very clear in the html. If you can't initially see them, they are quite small and are at the very far end of the page (you might need to scroll), the right arrow image is clearer on my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is : you are trying to change src value in img tag using css hover effects . I think i solved the matter by adding few Jquery functions .

```
<div style="margin:25px;">

<div class="slider" data-slick='{"arrows": true'}>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3052361/pexels-photo-3052361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/830891/pexels-photo-830891.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/373912/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462331/pexels-photo-462331.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162031/dubai-tower-arab-khalifa-162031.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/290595/pexels-photo-290595.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1823739/pexels-photo-1823739.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1769371/pexels-photo-1769371.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
    </div>

</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.slider').slick({
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/584799/pexels-photo-584799.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' id='prv'>",
nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/536/road-street-sign-way.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260' id='nxt'>"
    });
}); 


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#prv").hover(function(){
    $("#prv").attr("src", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/413195/pexels-photo-413195.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    }, function(){
    $("#prv").attr("src", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/584799/pexels-photo-584799.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  });
  $("#nxt").hover(function(){
    $("#nxt").attr("src", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/413195/pexels-photo-413195.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    }, function(){
    $("#nxt").attr("src", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/536/road-street-sign-way.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  });
});
```

Your CSS For Hover Effects is not Required